$\chi^2_2 = \operatorname{Exp}(1/2)$ — intuition?
A well-known ( and simple ) fact is that the chi-squared distribution with two degrees of freedom is the same as the exponential distribution with rate $1/2$:

Indeed, it is very easy to find
$$
\mbox{the PDF of}\ X^{2}\ \mbox{for}\ X \sim N\left(0,1\right),
$$
and then calculate its convolution with itself to find
$$
\mbox{the PDF of}\ X_{1}^{2} + X_{2}^{2}
$$
for a pair of independent
$X_{1},\ X_{2} \sim N\left(0,1\right)$.
It looks, however, like there should be a "higher level" explanation for why this is true.
What I'm looking for here is a direct connection between a pair of standard normal RVs and some Poisson process, which could convince a person that there should be some formula of this sort ( so one sees that indeed
$X_{1}^{2} + X_{2}^{2}$ measures the waiting time in some Poisson process, and it only remains to find the rate of the latter ).

Is there such a connection ?.




The memoryless property of the exponential distribution can be rewritten as $P(X_1^2+X_2^2>t+s) = P(X_1^2+X_2^2>t)P(X_1^2+X_2^2>s)$. Perhaps there is an intuitive way of showing this for a normal distribution which immediately implies that the sum of squares is distributed by an exponential

Jump to the Herschel-Maxwell chapter here.

Very nice, this is essentially showing the memoryless property then proving that it implies the density is exponential

@J.G. Indeed, this I knew, but haven't connected to the memorylessness property. Although this is not exactly what I was hoping for (the exponential distribution appears here as the unique family of memoryless cont. distr. rather than through a Poisson process), this is very cool!

Your question then becomes why $R^2$ is memoryless if $R$ is Rayleigh. The best I can offer is Pythagoras & a Jacobian.
